# Overriding overflow-x CSS property on iOS

Tags: css, iphone

We have a base style sheet for a mobile web app where we have html and body set to overflow-x:hidden to prevent any horizontal scrolling.

However on 1 page, we have an iframe that opens external sites, some of which are not necessarily mobile optimized, so we want to allow horizontal scrolling.

I thought I could just override the overflow-x:hidden, with overflow-x:auto !important, but it doesn't work.  The only way I can make it work is remove all notion of overflow-x, and the scrolling works fine.  It also works as expected in Safari + Chrome.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>         
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />

    <style>

      /* Styles from existing style sheet */
      html, body {
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

      /* Overrides */
      html, body{
        width:auto !important;
        height:auto !important;
        overflow-x:auto !important;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://starbucks.com"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried `overflow-x: visible;` instead? Also I don't believe the `!important`s are necessary.

Comment: sweet, visible works, thanks.  I still don't understand why auto won't work though.  I'll remove the !important's, they snuck in out of frustration.

Comment: @Brian Stoner: visible is the default value for `overflow` and its monoaxial counterparts. It means the content will visibly overflow the container. Auto on the other hand causes scrollbars to appear if there's an overflow. In Mobile Safari there is no notion of scrollbars though, so that's the problem.

Comment: ah, that makes sense.  Thanks for the responses, much appreciated.