# How to disable vertical scrolling but keep horizontal scrolling on iOS-devices?

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications

I'm sure you've scrolled on an iPad, and when you reached the bottom, you reveal a dark background behind the website. When you release your finger the webpage slides back again.

I'm making a web app that is the height of the iPad viewport. The width, however, is going to be wider than the viewport. So I want scrolling horizontally, but the vertical bounce-effect should be turned off.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS.

```
body {
    overflow:visible;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

This should work for all devices after the 5.1beta2 update to include overflow capabilities.

Edit: [Somebody else had this issue before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172109/overriding-overflow-x-css-property-on-ios) Perhaps this will work for you.

Comment: edit: i think i misunderstood ... you want the bounce turned off, and thats it right. here is the best i got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128196/iphone-html5-app-scrolling-question/3128400#3128400

Comment: It does stop scrolling, but now I can't scroll horizontally. That's the problem... But anyway, thanks for your time!