# overflow-x: auto on iPhone is not scrolling

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I have an iframe inside a div, which looks like:

```
<div align="center" style="z-index:0; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); overflow-x:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch"> 
    <a href="c1" data="c1"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="iframe-loader"></script>
</div>
```

I want the entry form to be scrollable on the x-axis, so that it can be used in mobile phones. This is working correctly on desktop and other phones, such as Android, but when using Safari in iOS the scroll is not present or works randomly.

Any possible fixes for this? Is this an iOS bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding overflow-x CSS property on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172109/overriding-overflow-x-css-property-on-ios)

Comment: Different case I believe... The solutions in that post are not helping

Comment: The align="center" attribute is deprecated. Use css instead.

Comment: Interesting, because they talk about not being able to use `overflow:auto` because scrollbars are not valid.  Sounds the same.

Comment: @SimplyCraig I think this is something else, possibly related to layered divs or something like that? None of those solutions work, and even setting a percentage width to the wrapper div doesn't make it scrollable.

Comment: Why the close vote? What's the answer for this? It's not a duplicate, unless someone can clearly post the solution for this iOS problem.

Comment: Is your phone updated? It works on my safari.

Comment: Even I test in ios simulator and phone it's working. If still it's not working then please can you give us case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw in your sources that you use bootstrap so why you don't just adapt the with to be all inside the screen without any scrolling (horizontal scrolling on cellphone is not really user-friendly for me).

If you really want to use scrolling, I recommend you to use:

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

instead of

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch;`

Have you tried to use `!important`?

Answer (score 2):

I just went to this website on my iPhone, and the form scrolled easily on the X-Axis using iOS 8.1. I also went to your site using iOS 6.1.6 on a 4th generation iPod touch. On this older version of Safari, the web form was still able to load properly and scroll easily on the X-axis.

If you are having issues with your webpage, it could be a bug specific to your version of iOS or Safari. But I have not had any issues, the scrolling is smooth and works consistently. Hopefully this outside test was of help to you. Good luck and cheers!

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Either that or the person has found a solution but does not want us to be notified. :p

Comment: Sorry! The solution was to use -webkit-overflow-scrolling-x: touch... However, it kinda fixed itself, as I had already used that, as it can be seen in my original post. Strange :S In any case, I just accepted one of  the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
    .class-name{
     overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make the form 'flexible' instead. Try using a percentage width in your CSS. For example `width:10%;`

Comment: Thanks.. but the scroll still doesn't work on iPhone :s